# Simple Django query

Tags: django

I have following model School,Grade(School as fk) and Students(Grade as fk). How do I retrieve all classes and students for a School given a schoolid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Student.objects.filter(grade__school=your_school_id)`

Comment: How to follow relations in a query seems to be the most common stumbling block for new Django programmers. Not sure why. Perhaps the documentation needs to be more explicit or draw more focus to it in general.

Comment: well, i think that it's the second... coz the first place is hold by dynamic filters: `Class.objects.filter(**dict)` :)

Comment: @chrisdpatt Yes, the documentation could be better